# Fast way to check if a region overlaps another (1-d) region

Tags: python

I have a huge set of regionssically thousands of points with a start and an end. I.e.:

[(3015, 3701), (4011, 5890), ....]

I also have another set of points (both start and end) where I want a quick way to test whether or not a region in this set overlaps a region in the other set. Is there a fast way to do this?

Thanks!

--EDIT--

@Spike Gronim answered my question with an Interval Tree.

Thanks, Spike!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Comment: how big can these points become? I mean the range of start and end?

Comment: In the tens of thousands. They are genomic coordinates.

Comment: do the range's in each list ever overlap other ranges in the same list?

Comment: Are the two lists ordered by start coordinate?

Comment: @Dting In the first list, with longer, but less regions no. In the other list which has many more points but smaller regions, yes.

@ypercube yes

Comment: Spike, Thank you. This answers my question completely!

Answer (score 0):

```
def test(lista, listb):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    found = False
    while a<len(lista) and b<len(listb):
        result = check( lista[a] , listb[b] )
        if result < 0:
            a += 1
            continue
        if result > 0:
            b += 1
            continue
        # we found overlapping intervals
        found = True
        return (found, a, lista[a], b, listb[b] )
    return found

def check( (astart, aend) , (bstart, bend) ):
    if aend < bstart:
        return -1
    if bend < astart:
        return 1
    return 0


lista = [(3015, 3701), (4011, 5890)]
listb = [(1,2), (100,200), (4500,6000)]
result = test(lista, listb)
print result
```

Answer (score -1):

Find the min/max endpoints of both regions then see if those overlap.

Comment: This is possible, but slow. If possible, I need a way to randomly access the potential overlap.